# Best software to do big number calculations quickly

Tags: soft-question, math-software

I am trying to do some work on some math conjecture. I am testing the conjecture numbers using very large math numbers (1000+ digits ). I am currently using python to test these numbers.

In the conjecture's calculation, I quickly need to multiply and divide a large number several times. Python can do this quickly(~3000 calculations per minute). Is there any other faster software to achieve this.

Comment: Have you tried Matlab? If you are in a university, you might be eligible for an academic license.

Comment: Mathematica, also. Anything which uses GMP under the covers is going to be pretty fast.

Comment: Matlab is not very good for arbitrary precision arithmetics.